# Automatic transfer between inline and fixed without JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, input

I was trying to program a snazzy CSS search box that had the background for my magnifying glass icon envelop the search bar. However, I had some problems as the search bar would switch to the next line when it wasn't enveloped. Here's my code:

```js
function searchProducts() {
     document.getElementById("searchbar").submit();
     
    }
```

```css
.embtn {
        position:absolute;
        top:0vh ;
        left: 0vw;
        border-radius: 5vw;
    
        padding: 0.2vw;
        color: red; 
        width: calc(2vw + 1vh); 
        height: calc(2vw + 1vh);
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
        -o-transition: background-color 2s ;
        -o-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: background-color 2s ;
        -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
        transition: background 2s, width 0.5s ease-out 0.5s;
    }
    .embtn:hover {
    
        
        -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
        -o-transition: background-color 2s ;
        -o-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: background-color 2s ;
        -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
        transition: background 2s, width 0.5s ease-out 0.5s;
     background-color: black;
        width: 30vw;
    
    }
```

```html
<form id="searchbar" style=" position:absolute; top:5vh ;left: 2vw; " method="post" action="index.php">
    <div class='swhole'>
    <div class='embtn'><div  id="searchproduct" style="font-size:calc(1vw + 1vh);cursor:pointer; display: inline;" onClick="searchProducts()">&#x1F50D;</div>
    
    <input id="search" style=" color: white; position:absolute; top: calc(((2vw + 1vh)/2)-(1vw + 1vh); );  ; left: 3vw; display: inline; border-style: none; outline: none; background: transparent;  width: 25vw; font-size: calc(1vw + 1vh); " type="text" placeholder=" Search..." name="search" required>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    
    </form>
```

This was fine up until the background shrunk to its normal size and then the search bar went to the next line.

I had a fiddle for this too: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rb68cjg1/1/)

Any ideas for how to keep this all on one line? I had it working earlier but it isn't working now.

:)

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I found was the way you were calculating the offset height for the input. `calc(((2vw + 1vh)/2)-(1vw + 1vh));` was pushing your input box below the icon. `top: 1vh` keeps it relatively inline.

Also reformatted your code to make it a little easier to read.

```css
.embtn {
    position:absolute;
    top:0vh ;
    left: 0vw;
    border-radius: 5vw;
    
    padding: 0.2vw;
    color: red; 
    width: calc(2vw + 1vh); 
    height: calc(2vw + 1vh);
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 2s ;
    -o-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 2s ;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: background 2s, width 0.5s ease-out;
}
.embtn:hover {
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 2s ;
    -o-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 2s ;
    -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: background 2s, width 0.5s ease-out;
 background-color: black;
    width: 30vw;
}

.form {
   position:absolute;
   top:5vh;
   left: 2vw; 
}

.input-icon {
  font-size:calc(1vw + 1vh);
  cursor:pointer;
  display: inline;
}

.input {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1vh;
  left: 3vw;
  display: table-cell;
  border-style: none;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  width: 25vw;
  font-size: calc(1vw + 1vh);
}
```

```html
<form id="searchbar" class='form' method="post" action="index.php">
  <div class='swhole'>
    <div class='embtn'>
      <div id="searchproduct" class='input-icon' onClick="searchProducts()">&#x1F50D;</div>

      <input id="search" class='input' type="text" placeholder=" Search..." name="search" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


<script>
function searchProducts() {
 document.getElementById("searchbar").submit();
 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake while applying a width on `.embtn` style. You are setting width `width: calc(2vw + 1vh);` instead it should be `width: calc(2vw + 1vw);`

I have made some changes in inline style sheet to make it perfect.
Below are those.

For searchproduct div:
`position:absolute; top:2px;`

For search input:
`top: 2px;`

See the Snippet below:

```js
function searchProducts() {
     document.getElementById("searchbar").submit();
     
    }
```

```css
.embtn {
        position:absolute;
        top:0vh ;
        left: 0vw;
        border-radius: 5vw;
    
        padding: 0.2vw;
        color: red; 
        width: calc(2vw + 1vw); 
        height: calc(2vw + 1vh);
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
        -o-transition: background-color 2s ;
        -o-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: background-color 2s ;
        -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
        transition: background 2s, width 0.5s ease-out 0.5s;
    }
    .embtn:hover {
    
        
        -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ;
        -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
        -o-transition: background-color 2s ;
        -o-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: background-color 2s ;
        -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
        transition: background 2s, width 0.5s ease-out 0.5s;
     background-color: black;
        width: 30vw;
    
    }
```

```html
<form id="searchbar" style=" position:absolute; top:5vh ;left: 2vw; " method="post" action="index.php">
    <div class='swhole'>
    <div class='embtn'><div  id="searchproduct" style="position:absolute; top:2px; font-size:calc(1vw + 1vh);cursor:pointer; display: inline;" onClick="searchProducts()">&#x1F50D;</div>
    
    <input id="search" style=" color: white; position:absolute; top: 2px; left: 3vw; display: inline; border-style: none; outline: none; background: transparent;  width: 25vw; font-size: calc(1vw + 1vh); " type="text" placeholder=" Search..." name="search" required>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    
    </form>
```

Test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/hcstLz7p/) also.

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet you shared, the search input element has a top value calculated with a very complex formula.

I would suggest to set a fixed top value. If you still want to calculate it, use CSS variables instead. chyeck the following example:

```
.foo {
  --widthA: 100px;
  --widthB: calc(var(--widthA) / 2);
  --widthC: calc(var(--widthB) / 2);
  width: var(--widthC);
}
```